# Collision of drawn line with PNG

Tags: actionscript-3

I'am working on maze game and don't understand how can I create collision of drawn line with .png. 
My maze itself is a .png file where waypaths represented with transparent part. Non-transparent part represents walls of a maze. Player's goal is to draw line walking on transparent part and don't hit walls.

My drawn line also contains BitmapDataStyle. Here's the code:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, f_enterFrameHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, f_mouseUp);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f_mouseDown);

    var m = new MovieClip();
    var w = stage.addChild(m);
    var g = m.graphics;
    var misdown = false;
    var bitmap:BitmapData = new mark_line;

    g.lineStyle(6,0x444444,1);
    g.lineBitmapStyle(bitmap);
    g.moveTo(0,0);

    function f_enterFrameHandler(e:Event)
    {
    if (misdown)
        f_drawLine();
    }

    function f_mouseUp(e:MouseEvent)
    {
    misdown = false;
    }

    function f_mouseDown(e:MouseEvent)
    {
    misdown = true;
    g.moveTo(w.mouseX,w.mouseY);
    }

    function f_drawLine()
    {
    g.lineTo(w.mouseX,w.mouseY);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't just test the mouse position? It is easier than checking raster vs vector.

Comment: It is against my concept of a game. I need to check a line.

Comment: Well, then **BitmapData.draw(...)** your line then compare it pixel by pixel to your PNG. As optimization measure, do not draw all the path, just the last piece +2 pixels to either side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect hit of two shapes, you have to use bitmapData.hitTest(). you can detect collision between any shapes from their bitmapData. to do that, you have to draw both of your shapes on bitmapData like line belo:

```
var shape1Bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(shape1MC.with,shape1MC.height,true,0x000000);
shape1Bitmap.draw(shape1MC);

var shape2Bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(shape1MC.with,shape1MC.height,true,0x000000);
shape1Bitmap.draw(shape1MC);

shape1Bitmap.hitTest(new Point(),shape2Bitmap):Boolean;
```

to continue using BitmapData.hitTest(), follow the orders here : https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()

http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/02/03/using-hittestpoint-or-hittest-on-transparent-png-images/

Good luck